# How to hide and unhide all objects within a collection

Tags: collections

I don't know if this is possible in Blender, but I have a collection full of a bunch of objects. Some are hidden from the viewport, and some are not.
Now I want to unhide all the objects within the collection at once. Is this possible?
I thought selecting all the objects and clicking the viewport toggle, while holding down the 'alt' key would do this, but it didn't.
Any ideas?

*But then again, with multiple objects selected, does holding 'alt' and clicking on a menu item affect all objects. I found some cases where this doesn't apply*

Comment: If you press Shift and click on the Hide in Viewport option (eye icon) it will hide or unhide all the collection's objects

Comment: Or Right Click on a collection and select Visibility -> Show All Inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do and what is the most comfortable for you. If you just don't want to see the whole collection in the viewport, click on the eye icon of the collection, no selection necessary and all are hidden in the viewport. But their individual toggle is still enabled, so if you move an object outside of the collection it would become visible.

If you want to make sure all individual toggles are disabled, you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the collection's eye icon (as @moonboots commented), this way the collection's eye icon and the individual toggles are disabled/enabled. Again no object selection needed. This is maybe useful if you want to disable almost all in a collection with many objects and only switch a few ones back. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> option works for the other toggles, too.

Then the most simple way of course is when you have all objects in a collection selected, just move your mouse to the viewport and hit <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them all. This way all the individual eye icons are disabled, but the one from the collection is not. Which means if you now move a visible object into the collection, it will stay visible although the others are hidden.

And then you have the collection's checkbox to include or exclude it from the view layer. Unchecking it will make the objects disappear completely from view and render and even in the *Outliner's* hierarchy at once.

However, this option switches all eye toggles back to enabled when you check it again. If you are working on a project and want to switch the complete collection on and off a few times while keeping some objects invisible in viewport, you need to use the *Disable in Viewports* icon (the monitor icon). This is not there in the *Outliner* by default, you have to set it in the *Filter* > *Restriction Toggles* options:

[image: restriction toggles]

Here you can see the behaviour of the *Hide in Viewport* (eye), *Disable in Viewports* (monitor) and *Disable in Renders* (camera) toggles: the eye is just a temporary option which switches back if you switch the collection from exclude to include, while the monitor and camera keep their setting. By the way, this does not apply for the collection's eye icon - that one keeps its setting when switching between excluding and including the collection.

[image: temporary and permant toggles]

Another note: the shortcuts for hiding options (<kbd>H</kbd> to hide selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide unselected and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all) are just changing, as their names say, the *Hide in Viewport* toggles (eye), not the *Disable in Viewports* toggles (monitor).